# String.empty unresolved in Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin

Like in Java and other languages I need to use **`x = String.Empty`** in my Kotlin code which conveys intent much better than the usual double quotes i.e. `x = ""`. It is also more readable for example in a code like this:

```
fun LocalDate.shortDate(daysToAdd: Long = 0L): String {

    val day = LocalDate.now()
            .plusDays(daysToAdd).dayOfMonth
    val prefixedDay = if (day in 1..9) "0$day" else "$day"

    return prefixedDay.let {
        //String.empty not being resolved
        it.plus(String.empty)
                .plus(
                        LocalDate.now()
                                .plusDays(1).month.name.substring(0..2)
                )
    }

}
```

I'm on **Kotlin 1.9** and when I opened the source code for `String` class I could not find the `empty` property. Obviously, the **`String.empty`** is not being resolved.

Is there any way to go around it or do we have to stick with the double quotes?

Comment: There is no `String.empty` in Java either though.

Comment: And you can always define your own `emptyString` global property.

Comment: Nice Tips @Sweeper and Phil, thanks for correction on Java, I was wrong.

Comment: If your main concern is readability, you could increase it by changing your code above to `it.toString() + LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).month.name.substring(0..2))`. But that won't work if the user is not English. In other languages, month names are not necessarily unique in the first 3 letters. You should use `month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.getDefault())`.

Comment: “String.Empty… conveys intent much better than the usual double quotes” — [\[citation needed\]](https://xkcd.com/285/).  I agree that most ‘magic numbers’ and other literals are a code smell — but `""` is _so_ widely used (in so many different languages), _so_ easily recognised, _so_ fundamental, _so_ clear, and _so_ much more concise than any alternatives, that I really think it's a special case.  (In much the same way that `0` and `1` are.)